# Changing upper break value to decimal using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, classification, python-script-tool, decimal-points

My ArcGIS Pro custom script tool is based off of a script that changes break values from a user's input. I believe I've done all I can troubleshooting the existing script. I'm suspicious of the tool parameters now.

**GOAL:** How do you change the Upper break value to a decimal? The user of this tool needs to be able to enter decimals. Here's the relevant part of the script that will set the break values:

```py
#class break values
classbreakvalues = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
breakvalues_list = classbreakvalues.split(";")
new_breakvalues_list = []
for brkvalues in breakvalues_list:
    newbreak = Decimal(brkvalues)
    arcpy.AddMessage(f'break value: {newbreak}')
```

Tool parameters:

[image]

Result:

[image]

What I've tried:

```py
#Results in neither decimal in layer symbology nor print statement
for brkvalues in breakvalues_list:
    newbreak = int(float(brkvalues))
    arcpy.AddMessage(f'newbreak: {newbreak}')

#prints these values
#break value: 40
#break value: 45
#break value: 60
#break value: 100

#No decimal in layer symbology, but decimal in print statement
for brkvalues in breakvalues_list:
    newbreak = float(brkvalues)
    arcpy.AddMessage(f'break value: {newbreak}')

#prints these values
#break value: 40
#break value: 45
#break value: 60.9
#break value: 100

#No decimal in layer symbology, but decimal in print statement
from decimal import Decimal
for brkvalues in breakvalues_list:
    newbreak = Decimal(brkvalues)
    arcpy.AddMessage(f'break value: {newbreak}')

#prints these values
#break value: 40
#break value: 45
#break value: 60.9
#break value: 100
```

I've used various Data Types in the tool's Properties-- String, Double, Long. Not one allowed a decimal in the symbology.

[image]

Comment: What if you use `str(brkvalues)`?

Comment: If I set it to ```newbreak = str(brkvalues)```, I get ```TypeError: must be real number, not str```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was further down in the script. I was too concentrated on one section. I needed to set the `upperBound` to a float. This is the part in the script where it takes the user input and sets the upper value in the symbology. Now I'm seeing decimals.

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')

#make sure fields in list are in same order as maps in project
fields =  ['VaccPercentageTotPop', 'VaccPercentage11to14', 'VaccPercentage0to18', 'VaccPercentage12to18',  
           'VaccPercentage14to16', 'VaccPercentage16to18', 'VaccPercentage19to64', 'VaccPercentage65Plus']

c = 0 #use counter to give a number to each map in for loop
for map in aprx.listMaps():
    arcpy.AddMessage(f'--- map: {map.name} ---')
    layers = map.listLayers()
    for layer in layers:
        arcpy.AddMessage(f'layer: {layer.name}')
        sym = layer.symbology   
        #Reset renderer 
        sym.updateRenderer('SimpleRenderer')
        sym.updateRenderer('GraduatedColorsRenderer')

        if hasattr(sym, 'renderer') and layer.name.startswith('BaseLayer'):
            Renderer = sym.renderer
            Renderer.classificationField = fields[c]
            #class break values
            classbreakvalues = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
            breakvalues_list = classbreakvalues.split(";")
            new_breakvalues_list = []
            for brkvalues in breakvalues_list:
                newbreak = brkvalues
                new_breakvalues_list.append(newbreak)
            classBreakValues = new_breakvalues_list
            #class break labels
            classbreaklabels = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
            breaklabels_list = classbreaklabels.split(";")
            classBreakLabels = breaklabels_list
            arcpy.AddMessage(f'class break label: {classBreakLabels}')

            # Run the Renderer.breakCount function to use the classBreakValues 
            # array parameters as the values, and create a counter.
            Renderer.breakCount = len(classBreakValues)

            i = 0 
            for brk in Renderer.classBreaks:
                brk.upperBound = float(classBreakValues[i]) #<--force to float
                brk.label = classBreakLabels[i]
                arcpy.AddMessage(f'brk label: {brk.label}')
                i+=1

                layer.symbology = sym
    c+=1
```

**EDIT:** I just learned I could have made life easier on myself had I used `arcpy.GetParameter()` instead of `arcpy.GetParameterAsText`.

> `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` Gets the specified parameter as a text string by its index position
> from the list of parameters.

> `arcpy.GetParameter()` The parameter is returned as an object.